# Intended design on how to implement cordite dgl tokens

Tags: cordite

I have a few questions regarding the cordite dgl tokens.
I want to tokenize an asset which is represented as LinearState.

1. Is there a way to only allow a single issuance of tokens?
2. Is the preferred way to link the tokens to other states through the TokenSymbol?
3. What is the intended design of accounts? One Account per usecase or one per TokenType?
4. How do I query if a specific token already exists? Is the only way to query for an account and look at the result (so there is no function to search for balance by TokenSymbol)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great questions, thanks!

1. It's not possible right now but it's definitely recognised as being desirable. It will require a change to the core which is fine. I think this work will require Corda 4, notably reference states and linear state pointer types for it to work. Notably, we will want:

   a. There are so many ways of limiting issuance: not only by final amount, but also by distribution rate, signing parties (in the case where multiple are required for the issuance) etc. We need means of inserting the notion of finite issuance into the token type, optionally. This will be either adding additional fields to the existing TokenType. Or better, making TokenType open so that it can be extended. Another way is to provide a field to a base type or interface that will encode the contract rules.

   b. we could transfer the token type as an attached StateAndRef, but we need to be conscious of the per tx storage, network, signing and verification cost of doing this. A better approach is to use the reference data feature in Corda 4 that we are eagerly waiting for.
2. If the other states are part of the same transaction that emits the tokens, then the linking is implicit. If the other state is not in the same transaction as the token, then linking for now, in Corda 3, would need to use TokenType descriptor. Alternatively, it can also reference a StateAndRef in the tx that generates the other state. The most efficient we think is to use Corda 4's reference states (scheduled for Dec/Jan this year I believe)
3. Accounts are designed to store tokens of multiple token types. They are really aligned for the business use-case and aren't limited by specific token types, unless you want to enfore that in the application layer.
4. Do you mean you want to get the balance of a TokenType across all accounts? You can certainly use the Corda's API to locate Tokens - this isn't exposed via Braid yet but could certainly could be. Another approach is to tag/alias all your accounts with the same tag e.g. `{ category:'all-accounts', value:''}` You can then do a `ledger.balanceForAccountTag({ category: 'all-accounts', value:''})` to get balances across all accounts. However, this returns the balances for all TokenTypes. What would the ideal API look like for you?